# Allow access to Firebase Firestore depending on user permissions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I want to build an iOS app where the users have different permissions to access a document. How can I give the user read/write access when he is an admin, only read when he is a viewer and no access otherwise to a document using Firestore rules? Every user is allowed to create new documents.

My Firebase Rules:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

How I added admin and viewers of each document

[image: Admin and Viewers]

When the users email (I'me using Firebase Auth) is on the list, he is admin or viewer.

I'me an iOS Developer and therefor have no experience with Java Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched a bit and came up with a solution:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /organizations/{organization} {
      allow create: if allowCreate();
      allow update, delete: if allowWrite();
      allow read: if allowRead();
    }
  }
  
  function allowCreate () {
    return request.auth != null;
  }
  
  function allowRead() {
    return resource.data.viewers.hasAll([request.auth.token.email]) || 
        resource.data.admins.hasAll([request.auth.token.email]);
  }
  
  function allowWrite() {
    return resource.data.admins.hasAll([request.auth.token.email])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I Am Android Developer but I Have solved your problem You should put a statement in your app to check if an account is Admin or not (example) { The User Input his email, and now we will chick if his account found in admins or viewers so we will use code (it's just example code)  `Create button  invisible and enabled=false  FireBase.child("Admins/"+inputuser).addValuelistener.(new AddValueListener....... if(snapshot.getValue.toString!=null){ the user is admin button=visble and enabled=true   }else{ the user is viewer }` I Hope you understand me

Comment: Yes, that would be a possible solution for not so private information. I need to perform the check if the user is admin/viewer already on server side for security reasons.